# How can I efficiently find Bitbucket repositories with recent commits via the REST API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

We have a deprecated Bitbucket instance and I'd like to pull data on which repositories are still actively committed to. Right now I'm using the `/repos` endpoint then iterating over that and calling `/projects/foo/repos/bar/commits?limit=1` for each one, which is incredibly slow (a few hours to run for almost a thousand repos).

Is there a more efficient API endpoint I could use to find repos or whole projects with recent commits?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the latest commit by each branch, you can try this way:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches
```

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/branches#get

or from the specific branch:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches/{name}
```

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/branches/%7Bname%7D

Hope it will help you. :)